# Using Formtastic with Sorcery. How do I set up the login form?

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.1, formtastic

This is basically a resource-less form, but the other examples don't seem to work. I'm using sorcery and formtastic. formtastic is working just fine for the new user form, but i can't seem to create a new session...

`<%= semantic_form_for 'sessions', :url => sessions_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do  %>
        <%= f.input :email %>
        <%= f.input :password %>
    <% end %>
        <%= f.buttons %>
<% end %>`

this is close, but it outputs

`<input id="sessions_email" name="sessions[email]" type="text" />`

instead of

`<input id="sessions_email" name="email" type="text" />`

so when i submit the form, i get a template missing error

`Template is missing

Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. `

i guess i just need to know how to set the 'name' attribute of the form specifically, but that seems like a bit of a hack. is there a more 'semantic' way to do this? please help thanks.

EDIT: here's the controller code per request...

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate, :except => [:show, :new, :create]
  before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,   :only => :destroy


  def index
    @title = "All users"
    @users = User.paginate(:page => params[:page])    
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 6)
    @title = @user.name
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @title = 'Sign up'  
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      Notifier.registration_confirmation(@user).deliver
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Sign up"
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @title = "Edit user"
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated."
      redirect_to @user
    else
      @title = "Edit user"
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User Removed"
    redirect_to users_path
  end

  def following
    @title = "Following"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.following.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  def followers
    @title = "Followers"
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @users = @user.followers.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    render 'show_follow'
  end

  private

    def has_valid_signup_code?(code)
      code == valid_signup_code
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
    end

end
```

thanks!

Comment: The problem is not the name of the input, that should be fine. It probably is about the things you do in the create action of your sessions controller. Could you provide the code?

Comment: You probably also have a sessions_controller.rb don't you? That code would be of more interest ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some kind of redirect after successful login. This is how the create action in my sessions controller looks like (note my controller is named `UserSessionsController` and not `SessionsController`):

```
def create
  if @user = login(params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password])
    redirect_back_or_to root_path, :notice => I18n.t("user_sessions.login_success")
  else
    flash.now[:alert] = I18n.t("user_sessions.login_failure")
    render :action => :new
  end
end
```

And this is the login form:

```
= semantic_form_for 'session', :url => user_sessions_path do |f|
  = f.inputs do
    = f.input :email
    = f.input :password

  = f.buttons do
    = f.commit_button
```